# Call to a member function where() on array session

Tags: laravel

When I add to the cart I get this error

[image: error]

I'm trying to add a product's into my cart. I've looked for an answer for this everywhere and the results said I just needed to add a return statement in my function. But I already have a return statement and it still doesn't work.

CartService.php

```
public function count($key)
{
    if (!$this->has($key)) return 0;
    return $this->get($key)['quantity'];
}

public function has($key)
{
    if($key instanceof Model) {
        return ! is_null(
            $this->cart->where('subject_id' , $key->id)->where('subject_type' , get_class($key))->first()
        );
    }
    return ! is_null(
        $this->cart->firstWhere('id' , $key)
    );
}
```

Comment: Please share more details, like the error message in text form and your attempts to resolve the problem

Answer (score 0):

I think this error is just because of cart variable is a array not a collection.

And when you apply where method on cart variable you need to convert cart variable as collection to apply method.

For that your **has function** may be like this:

```
public function has($key)
{
    $cart = collect($this->cart);
    if($key instanceof Model) {
        return ! is_null(
            $cart->where('subject_id' , $key->id)->where('subject_type' , get_class($key))->first()
        );
    }
    return ! is_null(
        $cart->firstWhere('id' , $key)
    );
}
```